# Replace multiple parts of URL

Tags: url, redirect, replace

I want to replace multiple parts of URL including its domain. Like for instance if something is found in url then replace it with something else. in below example only first part works, why not second?

```
window.location = url.replace('.jpg', '.mp4');
window.location = url.replace('abc', 'def');
```

What if I want to replace 3 things? this is only an example

www.**youtube**.com/**watch**?v=voMOmKMX**ZXM**

www.**google**.com/**hide**?v=voMOmKMX**ABC**

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by "What if I want to replace 3 things?"? Please clarify.

Comment: Updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `replace()` takes a string as its only parameter and also returns a string, you can chain multiple replace statements together, like this:

```
window.location = url.replace('.jpg', '.mp4').replace('abc', 'def');
```

So, if the value of `url` were to be this: `www.google.com/abc.jpg`, after calling the above, `window.location` would be set to `www.google.com/def.mp4`.